# How to retrieve all posts from a hosting database?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

I have complete backup of my old website which I downloaded while I had access to the hosting account.

I need to get access to all the posts that I made on that website ( Only plain text would also work.) I tried to search it in the database by navigating the file manager but didn't succeed.

I have the database transferred to another hosting account if that anyhow helps.
Thank You!

Comment: If you have a backup of your database, set up a new database on your local computer, import the database and issue the SQL statements to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: @Sirko , sorry but I didn't understand a single thing you mentioned. Could you please mention it in plain english?
Thanks

Comment: @KanchanSharma I'm affraid that is plain English ...

Comment: @KanchanSharma If you did not understand that sentence, I'm afraid that you're probably not able to retrieve the data on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what kind of database your web host was using, but I'm assuming it's MySQL. The solution depends on what kind of backup you have.

If you have the **binary files** (called .ibd, .frm, .myi etc) you can install MySQL on a local machine (virtual using for example VirtualBox or physical), stop the daemon and overwrite the local data files with the ones from the backup. Once that is done you can start the daemon and do an export of the relevant tables.

If you have **SQL files** (often call SQL dumps) then you can simply import them to any MySQL server using a console client or a GUI such as phpMyAdmin, HeidiSQL, SequelPro or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that are important.

1. Backup wordpress database in phpMyAdmin.
2. Backup wordpress folder (wp-content).

Text writing / posting contained in the database (phpMyAdmin), while some image content, plugins and themes in Foder wp-content.

hope to help you

Thanks